# time night differential computation in PHP

Tags: php, time, computation

I'm having problems in getting the night differential of an employee. Night differential starts from 10pm to 6am.

If an employee goes to work from 7pm to 5:30am there should be a night differential of 7 hours and 30 minutes.

How can I compute this using PHP?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

define('START_NIGHT_HOUR','22');
define('START_NIGHT_MINUTE','00');
define('START_NIGHT_SECOND','00');
define('END_NIGHT_HOUR','06');
define('END_NIGHT_MINUTE','00');
define('END_NIGHT_SECOND','00');

function night_difference($start_work,$end_work)
{
    $start_night = mktime(START_NIGHT_HOUR,START_NIGHT_MINUTE,START_NIGHT_SECOND,date('m',$start_work),date('d',$start_work),date('Y',$start_work));
    $end_night   = mktime(END_NIGHT_HOUR,END_NIGHT_MINUTE,END_NIGHT_SECOND,date('m',$start_work),date('d',$start_work) + 1,date('Y',$start_work));

    if($start_work >= $start_night && $start_work <= $end_night)
    {
        if($end_work >= $end_night)
        {
            return ($end_night - $start_work) / 3600;
        }
        else
        {
            return ($end_work - $start_work) / 3600;
        }
    }
    elseif($end_work >= $start_night && $end_work <= $end_night)
    {
        if($start_work <= $start_night)
        {
            return ($end_work - $start_night) / 3600;
        }
        else
        {
            return ($end_work - $start_work) / 3600;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($start_work < $start_night && $end_work > $end_night)
        {
            return ($end_night - $start_night) / 3600;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

var_dump(night_difference(strtotime('today 19:00'),strtotime('tomorrow 05:30')));
var_dump(night_difference(strtotime('today 10:00'),strtotime('today 19:00')));
var_dump(night_difference(strtotime('yesterday 10:00'),strtotime('today 08:00')));
var_dump(night_difference(strtotime('yesterday 23:00'),strtotime('today 04:00')));
```

outputs:

```
float(7.5)
int(0)
int(8)
int(5)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I'm studying your code now and currently constructing my own based on yours. Kudos!